# How to access request parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, haml

I am new to Rails, and I cannot figure out how to handle the :sort by portion of the code, from a haml view, below:

```
%th{:class=> title_header}= link_to 'Movie Title', movies_path( :sort_by => 'title' )
```

Do I catch this as some sort of parameter in my def index in the controller? Or does this require a complete new view?

When I click on the header, it goes to 
http://0.0.0.0:3000/movies?sort_by=title, which seems to be the same view as before. Somehow I need to wire it up to a method that sorts that column, but for the life of me, I can't figure out where this should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you seek is in the `params` object

```
def index
  sort = params[:sort_by]

  @movies = Movie.find(...) # TODO: get your movies

  if sort # if sorting is specified
    # TODO: sort @movies here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was battling with this for hours, and couldn't figure it out by myself.